# animate bar to percentage value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a bar that I'm trying to animate and I'm missing something here. Here is my HTML

```
<div class="bar"><span style="width: 74%;"></span></div>
```

and here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bar span').each(function(){
    var $percent = $(this).find('span').css('width') * 0.8;
    $(this).find('.bar span').animate(
        {width:$percent+"%"},
        {duration: 5000});
  })
});
```

I know I'm close...but can't seem to find the span to animate it.

Thank you all for your help. I wound up having it look for a number in the title tag as I couldn't get it to figure out the value of width. Here is the jquery I wound up with.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bar span').each(function(){
var $percent = $(this).attr('title') * 0.8;
$(this).animate(
    {width:$percent+"%"},
    {duration: 1000});
  })
});
```

Comment: Can not see any element with class reviewAttn_bar

Comment: my mistake...fixed it. I have two bars and one isn't going to be animated so I mixed up the class names.

Comment: Have you tried using the jQueryUI progress bar? http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/  Quite easy to use.

Comment: I did try it but couldn't get the bar to grow to the point specified in the style width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use .find(), you just have to use $(this) because you already selected the span with

`$('.bar span').each()`

so it should be...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.bar span').each(function(){
       var $percent = $(this).css('width') * 0.8;
        $(this).animate(
        {width:$percent+"%"},
        {duration: 5000});
    })
});
```

Comment: I changed it to where it looked for the number in a title tag as I just couldn't get it to see the style width.

Answer (score 0):

`css(width)` should return something like `N px`, so you either have to process that to get the value or you can use `height()`:

```
var $percent = $(this).width() * 0.8;
```

Also the effect is a little strange: see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/22sZN/).

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned by @rjg132234 you don't need the `.find()` method.
2. Your `.css('width')` shall return a fixed string. Not '74' which you are expecting. I'd suggest using a `data-` attribute.

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <span data-width="74">
    </span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bar span').each(function () {
        var $percent = $(this).data('width') * 0.8;
        $(this).animate({
            width: $percent + "%"
        }, 5000 );
    });
});
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/KqsRM/1/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on my comment.  I use jQuery progressbar for doing something similar as to what you are wanting.  The following is how it is accomplished.  It would be fairly straightforward to eliminate the need for the progressbar though.

**Html**

```
<div id="autorefresh-section">
    <div id="autorefresh-control">
        <label for="autorefesh">Auto-Refresh</label> 
           <input type="checkbox" id="autorefresh" checked="checked" />
    </div>
    <div id="countdown"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
/**
  * This function sets the time interval used to auto-refresh the page.
  */
function check_refresh(countdownValue, secondsRemaining) {
    var autorefresh = $("#autorefresh");

    if ($(autorefresh).attr("checked") == "checked") {      
        setTimeout(function() {
            var value = Math.round(secondsRemaining / countdownValue * 100);
            // consoleDebug("Seconds remaining: " + secondsRemaining);
            secondsRemaining -= 10;
            $("#countdown").progressbar("option", "value", value);
            if (secondsRemaining < 0) {
                reloadTab("all");
                check_refresh(300, 300);
            } else {
                check_refresh(countdownValue, secondsRemaining);
            }
        }, 10000);
    } else {
        $("#countdown").progressbar({ disabled: true });
    }
}
```